# S Pen Multi-Window SDK Proguard Rules

Tags: android, proguard, multi-window

I'm getting the following two warnings when building and Android project with proguard that has the S Pen SDK Multi-Window jar (2.2.5):

```
[proguard] Warning: android.sec.multiwindow.Constants$WindowManagerPolicy: can't find referenced class android.view.WindowManagerPolicy
[proguard] Warning: android.sec.multiwindow.MultiWindowManager: can't find referenced method 'java.util.List getRunningTasks(int,int,android.app.IThumbnailReceiver)' in class android.app.ActivityManager
```

I was able to get proguard to run successfully by adding the following line to my proguard config file:

```
-dontwarn android.sec.multiwindow.**
```

However I'm a little uncomfortable with just ignoring the warnings. In this case, the warnings are referencing a class and method in `android.jar`, so they will be there at runtime.

I'm wondering if it would be good to also include the proguard rule:

```
-keep class android.sec.multiwindow.** { *; }
```

It doesn't appear to affect the build in this case, but it seems like a good idea.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class and the method may be present in the Android runtime, but they are not present in android.jar, due to the @hide marking (so they are not endorsed as public API). If it works with -dontwarn, that's acceptable. A cleaner solution would be to create a version of android.jar that does include such classes, fields, and methods.

The -keep option doesn't really affect the problem. You can leave it out.